# Remove characters from a string based on ascii code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have a given string, using JavaScript, is it possible to remove certain characters from them based on the ASCII code and return the remaining string e.g. remove all chars with ASCII code < 22 from the string?

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out there are a lot of different solutions, here is a short overview (sorted from the fastest to the slowest)

## A simple for loop

```js
let finalString = "";
for(let i = 0; i < myString.length; i++ ) {
   if(myString.charCodeAt(i) < 22) continue;
   finalString += myString.charAt(i);
}
```

Speed (for the benchmark bellow): 82,600 ops/s ±1.81%

## For loop after splitting and filtering the string

```js
const newStringArray =  myString.split("").filter(e => e.charCodeAt(0) > 22)

let finalString = ""
for(let i = 0; i < newStringArray.length; i++ ) {
   finalString += newStringArray[i]
}
```

Speed (for the benchmark bellow): 55,199 ops/s ±0.53%
*33.17% slower*

## One liner with `.join`

```js
const newString = myString.split("").filter(e => e.charCodeAt(0) >= 22).join("");
```

Speed (for the benchmark bellow): 18,745 ops/s ±0.28%
*77.31% slower*

## One liner with `.reduce`

```js
const newString =  myString.split("")
  .filter(e => e.charCodeAt(0) > 22)
  .reduce( (acc, current) => acc += current, "");
```

Speed (for the benchmark bellow): 17,781 ops/s ±0.23%
*78.47% slower*

## Benchmark

The benchmark could be found here: https://jsbench.me/50k8zwue1p
[image: https://jsbench.me/50k8zwue1p]

Comment: i think the condition should be the other way around e => e.charCodeAt(0) >= 22

Comment: its funny to see that if you make the reducer function pure, so it creates a new string on every single call, is a tiny bit faster then the `acc += current` version:
`const newString =  myString.split("").filter(e => e.charCodeAt(0) > 22).reduce( (acc, current) => acc + current, "");`

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the string and for each letter use charCodeAt(letter) that way you know its ASCII code and then you can perform your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is possible using the `str.charCodeAt()` method of javascript.
You can convert the given string into an array of characters and then use the map method to compare each character with the ASCII code with which you want to compare your string characters with. 
This will return a new array that follows the condition and then you can just join that array to form a string again.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating may be faster than join for large strings.

So building on @WolveringDEV answers you can loop over the array and concatenate instead of join

```
const newStringArray =  myString.split("")
 .filter(e => e.charCodeAt(0) > 22)

let finalString = ""

for(let i = 0; i < newStringArray.length; i++ ) {
   finalString += newStringArray[i]
}
```

Comment: Well concatenating strings like that is the most inefficient way to do so. So my method will be (in worst case) equal. Running a quick benchmark shows that "join" is actually way faster:  https://jsbench.me/50k8zwue1p

Comment: our conditions are reversed, so your test is not relevant.

Comment: Noticed that and fixed it ;)

Comment: I think the reason why your code is running approximately 5% slower is the invocation of the lambda. With `.join` you've no such overhead ;)

Comment: you are right, I switched to a plain for and it becomes faster. Used you test and changed it a bit https://jsbench.me/50k8zwue1p/1

Comment: As it turns out there is a even, way more faster, way. I've updated my post.